# JSON feeds context within Drupal 7

Tags: json, rest, drupal, feed, drupal-feeds

I'm trying to connect to a REST web service with Drupal 7. Data is supplied via a url and I want to pull it into the D7 site to create and populate nodes. I'm using the feeds module to map the content and the JSONPath parser as the parser. I have also included Feeds HTTPFetcher Append Headers module so that I can add custom headers in to make sure it is JSON being returned and not badly formatted xml which I was getting before.

Custom headers:

```
Accept|application/json
Content-Type|application/json
```

I have a url that looks like `http://192.136.0.31:8080/places/getAll`

Further to the above I have the Devel module in place which is returning the feed array in the page using the code below in my template.php:

```
$request = drupal_http_request('http://192.136.0.31:8080/places/getAll', $options);
dpm(drupal_json_decode($request->data));
```

This is what Devel returns:

```
... (Array, 1192 elements)
   0 (Array, 17 elements)
      Address1 (String, 19 characters ) 1-2 The Road name
      Address2 (String, 9 characters ) Shuinnad
```

The problem I'm having is getting this into feeds and mapping to the relevant fields. I don't know what should go in the context field - I have tried `$...*`, `$.*`, $...[*] but no luck.

When I click on an Array element from the devel output it shows $...[0]['Address1'] which suggests that should be the context - no luck.

Quick Update - using the drupal_json_decode function I can split the array out how I need to using php

```
foreach ($json as $section => $items) {
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    //if ($key == 'Address1') {
    echo "$section:\t$key\t:&nbsp;$value<br>";
    //}
    // check whether the current item is an array!
    if(is_array($value)) {
        echo "$key is sub array:<br />";
        foreach($value as $subKey => $subValue)
            echo "$subKey:\t$subValue<br />";
    }
}
}
```

The question still stands, how do I replicate that in Feeds using the JSON parser?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try this module: [Feeds JSONPath Parser](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser)

Comment: I am already using the Feeds JSONPath Paser but I don't know what the context field should be when mapping the content into relevant fields.

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutorial](http://glassdimly.com/blog/tech/drupal-7-feeds-extensible-parsers-jsonpath-map-json-fields/feeds-extensible-parsers)

> Context: is where you put the JSONPath expression that represents the path to the array representing your data. For instance, in my file, this would be $.albums.data.*. If this were a PHP array, that would be basically

foreach($facebook['albums']['data'] as $value);

- See more at: http://glassdimly.com/blog/tech/drupal-7-feeds-extensible-parsers-jsonpath-map-json-fields/feeds-extensible-parsers#sthash.BrIutjfl.dpuf